# How hybrid test automation framework can be configured to pass configuration from excel sheet to load data of that configuration from an xml file?

Tags: xml, automated-tests, testng, pageobjects

I am having a lot of confusion understanding an automation test framework for a maven project (confidential). The following is a scenario with my own mimicked project structure.

Its a TestNG based framework with page object model also spring is used. There are two projects in eclipse `fb` and `fbutil`. `fb` deals with TestNG based execution with actual test scripts written in `src/test/java` with each page of the app under test, having its own class and its suites. In `src/test/resources` we have defined properties file for each of the classes under their respective packages, also there is one `xsd` package which contains a schema `pageData.xsd` for a `pageData.xml`. `pageData.xml`  will contain configuration for all the test cases  with custom  parent tag and its children. Each parent tag will have an `id` which will correspond to the test case's column in an excel sheet provided in `data` folder as `FbData.xlsx`. child tags will also be a custom tag and will contain values to be used in test case execution.

Now, those custom tags used in `pageData.xml`, we will be defining in `pageData.xsd`. This `pageData.xsd` will generate getters and setters for the the child tags through maven (I don't understand how but ). 
`fbutil` project is nothing but the classes used for excel reading purposes (ignore this)

[image]

So let's say if two test cases be :

**Test Case 1:** *Login and Logout*

**Test Case 2:** *Login and go to profile then logout*

**Excel data for two test cases looks like :**

[image]

`pageData.xml` would look something like:

```
<configuration id='config1'>
  <username>xyz</username>
  <password>wxy</password>
</configuration>
```

Now these values will be called using `object.getUsername()` and `object.getPassword()` in the actual test script.

How can I figure out these themes and how they interact, and what should I learn in order to understand this kind of design pattern in depth?

Answer (score 0):

So, I did my research and found the solution for this sort of design pattern for a hybrid automation test framework. Someone might get the benefit of it.

I used `maven-jaxb2-plugin` for generating classes and its getters and setters  from the schema `PageData.xsd` of `PageData.xml` which is providing data for my test script. And calling those getters in my test class by unmarshalling the xml.

### Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.fb.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>fb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>fb</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <suiteFile></suiteFile>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.35.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.35.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

</dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>src/test/java/${suiteFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <!-- jaxb plugin -->
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.13.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- the package for the generated java classes -->
                                <generatePackage>com.fb.test.xsd</generatePackage>
                                <!-- If the following not specified all xsd in resources are included -->
                                <schemaDirectory>src/test/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                                <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/generated</generateDirectory>
                                <generatePackage>com.fb.test.generatedClasses</generatePackage>
                                <!-- if you don't want old output -->
                                <removeOldOutput>true</removeOldOutput>
                                <!-- if you want verbosity -->
                                <!-- verbose>true</verbose -->
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

### PageData.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pageData xmlns="http://www.fbtest.com/pageData" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="../../src/test/resources/xsd/pageData.xsd ">

    <configuration id='config0'>
        <username>mno</username>
        <password>pqr</password>
    </configuration>
    <configuration id='config1'>
        <username>xyz</username>
        <password>wxy</password>
    </configuration>
    <configuration id='config2'>
        <username>abc</username>
        <password>def</password>
    </configuration>
</pageData>
```

### pageData.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid Technologies Online Tools 1.0 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.fbtest.com/pageData" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="pageData">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="configuration">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="username" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="password" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Now, In the test script in `src/test/java` under package `com.fb.test.profile` I have `Profile.java` which does nothing but prints the values from xml.

### Profile.java

```
package com.fb.test.profile;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.fb.test.generatedClasses.*;
import com.fb.test.generatedClasses.PageData.Configuration; 

public class Profile {
  @Test
  public void f() throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException {
      JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.fb.test.generatedClasses");
      Unmarshaller unmarshler = context.createUnmarshaller();
      PageData data = (PageData) unmarshler.unmarshal(new FileInputStream("data/EnvironmentOne/PageData.xml"));
      for(Configuration conf: data.getConfiguration()){
          System.out.println(conf.getUsername());
          System.out.println(conf.getPassword());
      }
  }
}
```